# How to get request data from axios.get to Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, get, store

I'm new in Redux. Can somebody explain, how can I get request data from Get

```html
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/v3/products', {
            params: {
                pageNumber: 1,
                pageSize: 500,
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({result: response.data});
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error TestMethod', error);
            })
            .then(function () {
                // always executed
            });
    }
```

And place it in store in Redux

```html
const initState = {
    products: [
        {id: 1, title: 'first'},
        {id: 2, title: 'second'},
        {id: 3, title: 'third'},
        {id: 4, title: 'fourth'},
        {id: 5, title: 'fifth'},
    ],
};
```

Are there any methods?

Comment: I've got rootReducer with initState, Should I place code from Get request inside for example?

Comment: I know how to place it in states, but how I can grab it from Get and place it to store, it's pretty difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside reducer place a case in switch say...

```
case FETCH_DATA: { 
  return {...state, data: action.payload}
}
```

Now you have reducer code in place. Inside then block dispatch action {type:FETCH_DATA, payload:response.data}

```
.then(response => {
            this.setState({result: response.data});
        })
```

Comment: You mean I should place get request code inside reducer?

Comment: So I need to use this get request, if my array named 'products', I should just change result to products? and thats'it?

Comment: Yes correct result will be products. So I need to use this get request ? (this depends on api/ service). Hope I answered both questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use middleware to handle this type of redux side effects. You can use either
[redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

redux-thunk documentation explains `Why Do I Need This`

> Thunks are the recommended middleware for basic Redux side effects logic, including complex synchronous logic that needs access to the store, and simple async logic like AJAX requests.

You can also use redux-saga which does the similar task.